# Windows 7 and Windows 8 progress "ring" controls

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, windows-7

How can I create a native "progress ring" control using the WinApi?

I can't find anything on MSDN apart from the "ProgressRing" class for Windows 8 modern UI apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressring

I want to be able to use this from a pure win32 app on Windows 8 and have it draw the "spinning balls". But on Windows 7 it should be the "blue circle". I know for Windows 7 that the blue icon is the default mouse busy cursor which could be rendered. For Windows 8 I can't find the actual resource that it uses.

Update: I want to paint this onto a window rather than set it as the mouse cursor, I should have clarified this - even so the busy cursor on Windows 8 is not the "spinning balls" animation.

Comment: You intend your app to be unresponsive, I mean, it's a requirement?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `LoadCursor()` with the respective cursor and pass the result to `SetCursor()` (if you want to set it as a cursor) - or use it for your own means.  In the former case, it's `IDC_WAIT` that you want.

Like so:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
```

Keep in mind, Windows will keep resetting it under certain circumstances - which might make it seem like it does not work.  It might be appropriate in your case (I doubt it though) to use it in response to `WM_SETCURSOR`.

In the latter case (where you just want to use the cursor for your own means), you can use `DrawIcon()` on the `HCURSOR` you get from `LoadCursor()`.

Comment: I've updated the question - I didn't want to actually set the cursor but rather pain this cursor/icon onto my window. But there doesn't appears to be a cursor file for the Windows 8 spinner.

Comment: I know - you can render the `HCURSOR` you get from `LoadCursor()` using `DrawIcon()`.

Comment: Ah cool, I didn't know that was possible :) what about the Windows 8 spinner icon though?

Comment: You will not be able to do that without XAML (Metro), since that is defined far higher up than the Win32 API.  You'll have to re-create something yourself :).

Comment: Its not possible to create a XAML style window hosted inside a win32 app? :(

Comment: I've not had much experience - but Google did find me this which might be of use to you: http://blogmfc.com/2011/09/27/hello-world-c-metro-style-app/